# .NET CORE Wwebapi HTTPS - Kestrel TLS private key error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, https, ssl-certificate, kestrel-http-server

When trying to reach my .NET CORE webapi through https I get the error:

[Kestrel error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpKoC.png)

I load the self signed certificate that I generated from the certificate store. Loading it works fine but when it's used for the tls handshake there seems to be something wrong with the Private key.

The thing is, whenever I put a watch on the PrivateKey property of the X509Certificate2 object that contains my certificate, it works fine. So somehow my PrivateKey isn't loaded unless I put a watch on it or I explicitly access the private key before using the certificate (which would work but there has to be a cleaner solution). The permissions also seems fine since I can perfectly use the certificate once I access it first.

This is my Kestrel setup:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            string lovThumbprint = "d822eebae68129f0fd10295060963bbf41101231";
            var lovCertificateFromStore = GetCertificateByThumbprint(lovThumbprint);

            var hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder
                    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
                    {
                        
                        logging.AddConsole();
                        logging.AddDebug();
                        logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
                    })
                    .UseKestrel(
                    options =>
                    {                        
                        options.AddServerHeader = false;
                        options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5001, listenOptions =>
                        {
                            listenOptions.UseConnectionLogging();
                            listenOptions.UseHttps(lovCertificateFromStore);
                        });
                    }
                )
                    
                    .UseUrls("https://10.32.3.5:5001")
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
            return hostBuilder;
        }
```

And this is the function to retrieve my certificate from the certificate store:

```
private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateByThumbprint(string povThumbprint)
        {
            X509Certificate2 LovLocalCer = new X509Certificate2();
            var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            var certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, povThumbprint, validOnly: false);
            //If I uncomment this it works
            //Console.WriteLine(certificates[1].PrivateKey);
            Console.WriteLine("test");
            if (certificates.Count > 0) 
            {
                LovLocalCer = certificates[1];
            }
            store.Close();
            return LovLocalCer;
            
        }
```

Comment: Are you putting the cert into the store in the same process, or has it already been there a while?  It sort of sounds like you've loaded the cert from a PFX then put it into the cert store, but didn't specify PersistKeySet when loading the PFX (which should be used when, and only when, loading from the PFX into a persisted cert store).